# Understanding EOS SUBCKT behavior

Tags: spice, subcircuit

I'm trying to modify an op amp to simulate its worst case behavior at end of life.  In the common mode effect section of the LM124/NS I have the following

```
EOS 7 1 POLY(1) 16 49 1E-3 1
```

What is the function of EOS?  I've been searching online for some information about what it does but to no avail.

Thanks

Comment: How many and where used? Electro-Over-Stress diode??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a voltage dependent input offset source

> The offset voltage-source, Eos, provides a supply voltage dependent
>   input offset voltage and reflects the error voltages from the power
>   supply rejection ratio stage, the thermal effect stage, and the
>   noise-voltage source. Below is a diagram of the Eos polynomial-source
>   and the effects that correspond to each term.

[image]

From: [AN-840 Development of an Extensive SPICE Macromodel for "Current Feedback" Amplifiers](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/snoa247b/snoa247b.pdf)

Answer (score -1):

In standard SPICE an 'E' element is a voltage-controlled voltage source. So, EOS is just a VCVS named "EOS". The standard VCVS requires four node numbers: the first two are the output nodes and the second two define the controlling voltage. The final parameter is a gain factor. In this case you may have a non-linear gain function, but the syntax is a little odd. Without more context it's hard to be sure.